# Small, Empty Partition

Tags: partitioning, disk-management

I was installing [Gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org/) when I ran into out-of-room errors, so I had to go back into Windows to do some partition resizing.  In the Disk Management tool, I noticed that there is a small, empty partition in addition to the Windows and Linux partitions.  The tool lists it as a 39 MB primary partition.

Is this safe to delete?  What is it there for?

EDIT: Some more details about the partitions:

- [No name] 39 MB healthy EISA (mystery partition)
- RECOVERY (D:) 14.65 GB healthy NTFS (for backups and such, factory-made)
- OS (C:) 449.07 GB healthy NTFS (Windows)

Comment: Can you provide additional details about the partitions such as their types and file allocation system (i.e. FAT)?

Comment: @Zian Sure.  See my edit.

Comment: If you had given the output of the `list partition` command from `diskpart`, you would have provided enough information for people to give you more than "_If_ you have a Dell, it's _most likely_ this." answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I've seen a small EISA partition like that before, it's been the storage area for the Dell recovery and diagnostics tool (not the actual OS image or anything; just the tools themselves). If you have a Dell (or any other mainstream manufacturer like HP), that's likely what the partition holds.

Comment: It would be a bad idea to delete it, then?  (Not that I would; it's too small to be worthwhile.)

Comment: @Maxpm I'd say so. Besides, you've got tons of other space; no need to cause potential problems. (Also worth noting is that the recovery image in the second partition is most likely useless without the first partition).

Comment: It is probably a diagnostic tool partition. Dell laptops have such such a partitions that is accessed by holding the Fn key during boot and contains a self-test suite. I would keep it, it's handy if your computer ever starts acting up.